# Different hover colors in help page

Tags: bug, help-center, design

Mouse hover "See new questions" button:
[image: pic1]

Mouse hover "Ask a question" button:
[image: pic2]

Mouse hover "Visit the Help Center" button:
[image: pic3]

As you can see, when I hover my mouse over the "See new questions" button or the "Visit the Help Center" button, the text of the button turns blue. When I hover over the "Ask a question" button, the text stays white.

I was wondering if this was [by-design](/questions/tagged/by-design) or not, since the blue text on a blue background is quite hard to read.

> EDIT: I just found out that the text remains white after clicking the button for the first time. If my theory is correct, then new users will see all blue text on hover, which would make it quite confusing for them.